# Got error while using await async - "Uncaught (in promise): canceled"

Tags: angular, async-await, devextreme

I am getting an error "Uncaught (in promise): canceled" while using the following code

```
async allowPaging(checked) {
      for (let i = 1; i <= this.dataGrid.instance.pageCount(); i++) {
        var data = this.dataGrid.instance.getVisibleRows();
       for (let item in data) {
         if (data[item].rowType == "data") {
           if (data[item].data.canSkip == false) {
             pagingData.push(i - 1);
            break;
           }
        }
        }
        clearInterval(this.myInterval)
        console.log(this.myInterval,"Interval");
        await this.dataGrid.instance.pageIndex(i)
  }
```

`"this.dataGrid.instance.pageIndex"` is used to page the page index. It is a property of devextreme data grid

Do let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: `this.dataGrid.instance.pageIndex(i)` Is this function returning promise?

Comment: which version of that lib are you using?

Comment: I am using DevExtreme DataGrid

Comment: What version? @Param

Comment: devextreme 17.2.10

Comment: @VivekKumar I am not sure about it.